# Unable to configure xDebug despite editing the appropriate INI file on Mac

Tags: php, macos, config, ini

I've been trying to configure xDebug to start up when I load a page open on PHPStorm.  I've basically followed the same procedures on setting this up on my Mac, as I did on Windows.  On Windows it works as it should, however on my Mac, when I try to set the remote_autostart and other necessary flags for xDebug on the INI file, they don't seem to get applied when I look at the PHP configuration loaded in PHPStorm.

I've tried restarting the IDE, and PHP, and even edited the ext-xdebug.ini file which was also additionally parsed with the primary ini file, and nothing.

Both PHP and xDebug was installed with Homebrew, and xDebug is being recognized as the debugger, but for some reason the ini files supposedly getting parsed, aren't.

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Anyone able to help me with this?  I'm out of ideas.

Comment: ANYONE at all????